How to start docker desktop using command line on linux
Docker desktop is working fine, I would like to be able to start it using a command line because I wrote a bash script that start every software I need. There does not seem to be a docker-* command that would achieve this.
I am using the latest ubuntu LTS
Thanks in avance

It seems that this command is doing the trick :
systemctl --user restart docker-desktop

